# Powershell - Fatal error in Launcher - Pip install | Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-import

I created a **virtual environment** using **PowerShell** for a python program. Installed various modules needed for the program. The reason I install the virtual environment is because of the error of missing imports that occurred to me earlier. Throughout this work, I've used **Visual Studio Code** for writing the code and debugging it.

When I resumed my work on the program, I saw 2 modules showing missing imports i.e. "SpeechRecognition" and "wikipedia". In the terminal put the following code in the virtual environment:

```
pip install wikipedia
```

and this was the output:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"E:\\School Collage And Files\\visual studio\\QuantumMKI\\quan\\Scripts\\python.exe"  "E:\\SchoolCollageAndFiles\\visualstudio\\QuantumMKI\\quan\\Scripts\\pip.exe" install wikipedia': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The same error occurred for SpeechRecognition

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

and received the same output:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"E:\School Collage And Files\visual studio\QuantumMKI\quan\Scripts\python.exe"  "E:\SchoolCollageAndFiles\visualstudio\QuantumMKI\quan\Scripts\pip.exe" install SpeechRecognition': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Here is the whole output of the terminal for reference:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS E:\SchoolCollageAndFiles\visualstudio\QuantumMKI> & e:/SchoolCollageAndFiles/visualstudio/QuantumMKI/quan/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(quan) PS E:\SchoolCollageAndFiles\visualstudio\QuantumMKI> pip install wikipedia
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"E:\School Collage And Files\visual studio\QuantumMKI\quan\Scripts\python.exe"  "E:\SchoolCollageAndFiles\visualstudio\QuantumMKI\quan\Scripts\pip.exe" install wikipedia': The system cannot find the file specified.

(quan) PS E:\SchoolCollageAndFiles\visualstudio\QuantumMKI> pip install SpeechRecognition
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"E:\School Collage And Files\visual studio\QuantumMKI\quan\Scripts\python.exe"  "E:\SchoolCollageAndFiles\visualstudio\QuantumMKI\quan\Scripts\pip.exe" install SpeechRecognition': The system cannot find the file specified.

(quan) PS E:\SchoolCollageAndFiles\visualstudio\QuantumMKI>
```

My expectation was the installation of all these modules without exception.

NOTE: (quan) is the virtual environment of the program.

Comment: Could you try  `python -m pip install wikipedia`? And could you update the pip? If it still does not work, could you create a new virtual environment to check whether you can install `wikipedia`?

Comment: Thank you. Inside the virtual environment, both the modules get installed correctly without error.

Comment: The problem has been solved?

Comment: Yes!!! I ran the code you gave and it ran smoothly.

Comment: Glad to hear that.